# MPAndroidChart: HorizontalBarChart runs off screen first time displayed only

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am displaying data from an API call using a `HorizontalBarChart`. The first time the call is run the chart runs off the screen when displayed:

[image]

If I resubmit the call, the chart is now sized correctly:

[image]

When my app receives a successful network response, the following code is executed (helper methods not displayed):

```
public void displayBarChart() {
    barChart.setData(getBarData());
    barChart.setTouchEnabled(false);
    barChart.setFitBars(true);
    barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    configureXAxis();
    configureYAxis();

    barChart.invalidate(); // refresh
}
```

The layout code for `barChart` is:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
            android:id="@+id/bar_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
```

`barChart` is nested within a `LinearLayout` that is itself inside a `ScrollView`. All of these views have `layout_width="match_parent"`.

Any idea what's going on here? It seems that for the first call somehow `barChart` doesn't have the correct awareness of the width required, but subsequent calls reset it. Thanks!

## Update:

After some experimentation, I determined that I needed to execute `setData()` *after* calling `configureXAxis()`, which is defined as

```
private void configureXAxis() {
    final XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();

    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false); // no axis line
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false); // no grid lines
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(2);
    xAxis.setTextSize(16f);

    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(final float value, final AxisBase axis) {
            return labels.get((int) value);
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone know why this reordering is important for the bar chart to display correctly?